# How to go to the next activity using textView in Android

Tags: android-intent

For example, when i reached the score of 26 (26 is inside textview) then my activity will stop and will go to the next activity. How can i do this? Thanks in advance .

Comment: please add your current relevant code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are populating the text in the TextView within your app somehow, so you could just check the text value when you call TextView.setText().

When the value == 26, then use the following code to open the next activity:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityName.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Alternatively, you could have a thread which checks for the TextView object's text value periodically, if you really needed to do it that way. I don't think you can get a callback for a TextView as it's your app that is populating it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below...

MainActivity.java

```
package com.xxx.yyy.testapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.cloudant_crud_integration.android01.testapp.R;
import com.cloudant_crud_integration.android01.testapp.SecondActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        final Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text View value before: " + tv.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString()) + 1));
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text View value After: " + tv.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString()) == 26) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                Message m = new Message();
                m.obj = 0;
                messageHandler.sendMessageDelayed(m,10000);
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First take a textview in xml. Then define a textview in activity page then follow the code below...On the below code textview_id is the id you have written in the xml file and CurrentActivity is the name of that activity you are writing the code and NextActivity is the name of the Desire activity you want to go..

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textview = findviewById(R.id.textview_id);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent in = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
          startActivity(in);  
        }
    });
```

}